# Python How to GET Image and then POST (via requests library)

Tags: python, django, post, get, python-requests

I am using python to try and `get` an image from one API, and then `post` it to a separate API.

So far I have this code:

```
def create_item(token, user_id):
    url = '<api_url_to_post_to>'
    headers = {"Authorization": "Token {0}".format(token)}

    image_url = '<some_random_image_url>'
    image_obj = requests.get(image_url)

    data = {
        "image": image_obj.content
    }

    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=data)
    response = r.json()

    print(response)

    return response
```

The issue is that when I try to `post` it to the second API, I get a "File extension '' is not allowed." error. This is obviously a custom error message, but it signifies that there is something wrong with the `file` that I am `post`ing.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: should your header also include the content type? but also what do the docs say about the api you are posting to?

Comment: @aws_apprentice the API doesn't require any headers - it accepts a `post` perfectly fine when using a file using postman. I just need python to download the image as if it is a regular image, so I will be able to `post` it to the new API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying the file type, just `image_obj.content` is the raw binary image:

```
r = requests.post(
    url, 
    headers=headers, 
    files={'image': ('my_image.jpg', image_obj.content, 'image/jpg')})
```

This should add the correct headers to the multipart boundary for the image.

If you don't know for sure the content type, you might actually get it from the headers of your previous response: `image_obj.headers['Content-Type']` should be "image/jpg" but for a different image it might be "image/png".

Comment: Amazingly, I figured this out a few seconds ago lol. Do you by any chance know how to pull the image name w/ extension and image type from the `get` request, so I don't hard-code it and make an assumption?

Comment: `image_obj.headers['Content-Type']` gives you the content type that you can use as the last parameter. `image_obj.url` is the url where it was fetched so probably the last path component would be the filename: `image_obj.url.split('/')[-1]` could be what you want. However if the image is generated with a script then you'll just see the script name there.

Comment: Absolutely amazing, thank you so much - I wish I could upvote this twice!

Answer (score 0):

It wants a file extension, I'd hazard a guess that `image` should be `image.<SOME_FORMAT>`.

Comment: How would I append a file extension to a `request.content` object? And shouldn't the downloaded file have that, since I am `get`ting a `.png` file?